# wxPython wx.FileDialog does not show wildcard filter on MacOS

Tags: wxpython

Using wxPython (3.0.2) on MacOS (10.13), I would like to open a file dialog with a wildcard filter. To do so, I tried the following snippet:

```
import wx

app = wx.App()

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'win.py')

# Create open file dialog
openFileDialog = wx.FileDialog(frame, "Open", "", "", 
                                      "Python files (*.py)|*.py", 
                                       wx.FD_OPEN | wx.FD_FILE_MUST_EXIST)

openFileDialog.ShowModal()
```

that I borrowed from [here](https://pythonspot.com/wxpython-file-dialog/)

The dialog pops up **but** without the wildcard filter widgets. The same code works as expected on ubuntu-xenial. Would you have any idea of what is wrong with that snippet and how to fix this to make this code OS independant ?

Answer (score 0):

The following system option has to be set:

`wx.SystemOptions.SetOption(u"osx.openfiledialog.always-show-types","1")`

In doing so, a combo box for selecting the files according to a set of file filters will be available when opening a file dialog.